How to configure XShell so that PgDn work properly in bash?
The key PageDown types a ~ in my bash session instead of showing next command. Why does this happen and which settings do I need to change?
In vi key works as expected.
I did as described in How to configure PuTTY so that Home/End/PgUp/PgDn work properly in bash? for PuTTy
Also uncomment in /etc/inputrc
# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward

But it does not work.
What is the solution for XShell? Also i tried from Windows ssh.
If it is important, I have Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Upd: After few hours I have fount solution in history-search-forward not working in Ubuntu 18.04
